# Spring Framework | Force the browser to download a file without redirecting to a new page

Tags: ajax, spring, redirect, download, modelandview

There's this application I'm working on that using Spring 3.x libraries. Now, We have a download page that contains 'n' number of links where 'n' is usually greater than 10.
What I've done is that I've created a URL pattern such as:

```
/sec-download.do?p=10001
```

Clicking on the download link calls a controller that performs some validations and then generates a valid CDN link that can be downloaded by the browser. Here is a sample code snippet:

```
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    final Map<String, Serializable> secureAssetModel = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
    String downloadComponent = getRequestHelper().getStringParameterOrAttribute(request, ExtWebConstants.REQUEST_PARAM_DOWNLOAD_COMPONENT, "");
    ModelAndView resultView = null;
    if (downloadComponent == StringUtils.EMPTY) { // For regular web downloads.
        String requestParamsEncoded = getServetRequestHelper().getStringParameterOrAttribute(request, ExtWebConstants.REQUEST_PARAM_DOWNLOAD, "");
        String requestParamsDecoded = new String(Base64.decode(requestParamsEncoded.getBytes()));
        <snip>......<snip>
        <snip>......<snip>
        <snip>......<snip>
        resultView = getWebResultView(errorType, requestParamsDecoded, request);
    } 
    return resultView;
}

private ModelAndView getWebResultView(final DownloadErrorType errorType, final String requestParamsDecoded, final HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView resultView = null;
    final Map<String, Serializable> secureAssetModel = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
        String downloadURL = downloadService.getEvalDownloadLink(filePath);
        <snip>......<snip>
        <snip>......<snip>
        <snip>......<snip>
        resultView = new ModelAndView("redirect:" + downloadURL);
        return resultView;
}
```

the method getWebResultView()'s variable downloadURL gets the actual download link (http://download.xyz.com/xxx.exe?p=111) which gets wrapped in a ModelAndView as a redirect URL. This modelandView eventually gets returned from the method handleRequestInternal().

Now, the problem here is that for FF and Chrome, once I click on the download link, the browser download popup opens up and asks for the user to save it (all this time while staying on the same page).
On Internet Explorer however, the view gets redirected to another page and then the download starts. This means that to download the next file, the user would have to hit the browser back button and start the next download.

I understand that this could be because I'm actually redirecting to the download URL. Wondering if I could have a behavior similar to FF and chrome in MSIE so that it can download the file while staying on the same page?

Would appreciate any inputs.
Regards.

Comment: Since I could not arrive at any optimized solution, for now, I have created a new <iframe> within the page and set the controller URL to this iframe. This could fix the issue for now. I'll see if I can find a better solution.